# Json Deserialization

Tags: c#, android, .net, json

I want to use json to my android project. I am having some problem how to use json with .net. My code  :

```
    string stroutput = "";

           try
    {
        string conStr = @"data source=.;database=Kelepir;Integrated Security=True;";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        connection.Open();
        string myquery = "select ProductID,ProductName,CategoryName,UnitPrice from Products";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myquery, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var nes = new
            { 

                ProductID = reader["ProductID"].ToString(),
                ProductName = reader["ProductName"].ToString(),
                CategoryName = reader["CategoryName"].ToString(),
                UnitPrice = reader["UnitPrice"].ToString()
            };
            stroutput = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(nes);
            Response.Write(stroutput);
        }
    }
          catch (Exception ex)
    {
        stroutput = "ERROR : " + ex.Message;
    }
```

But my json has not this marks : ",", and "[ ]".
My output :

```
 {"ProductID":"1","ProductName":"Şeker","CategoryName":"Tatlı","UnitPrice":"20"}
{"ProductID":"2","ProductName":"Kuruyemiş","CategoryName":"Tuzl","UnitPrice":"200"}
{"ProductID":"3","ProductName":"Baklagil","CategoryName":"Sebze","UnitPrice":"100"}
{"ProductID":"4","ProductName":"Bulgur","CategoryName":"Sebze","UnitPrice":"10"}
```

I want this format to my code :

```
       { "table_name": 
                         [ 
{"ProductID":"1","ProductName":"Şeker","CategoryName":"Tatlı","UnitPrice":"20"},                        {"ProductID":"2","ProductName":"Kuruyemiş","CategoryName":"Tuzl","UnitPrice":"200"},
{"ProductID":"3","ProductName":"Baklagil","CategoryName":"Sebze","UnitPrice":"100"},
{"ProductID":"4","ProductName":"Bulgur","CategoryName":"Sebze","UnitPrice":"10"}]

    }
```

How I can do this ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a shot:

```
var rowList = new List<object>();       
while (reader.Read())
        {
            var nes = new
            { 

                ProductID = reader["ProductID"].ToString(),
                ProductName = reader["ProductName"].ToString(),
                CategoryName = reader["CategoryName"].ToString(),
                UnitPrice = reader["UnitPrice"].ToString()
            };
            rowList.Add(nes);

        }
var serializeMe = new {table_name = rowList }
stroutput = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(serializeMe );
Response.Write(stroutput);
```

You are serializing each row.  What you want to do is pacakge each row into a colleciton and then serialize the collection as a whole.

Comment: thanks for reply :)) I changed this code and work it :)